# htaccess getting parameter from url and redirecting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, regex-group

I want to redirect the search result page to a new one. The old url looks like this:

```
/תוצאות_חיפוש:search_keyword
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
/?s=search_keyword&post_type=product
```

The `search_keyword` is what the user looks for, meaning the term he's looking for. That means this shouldn't be changed. For example, if someone search for "shirts", the old url will look like:

```
/תוצאות_חיפוש:shirts
```

While the new one will look like:

```
/?s=shirts&post_type=product
```

I have tried multiple solution I found here on StackOverflow but none did the trick.

How can I create this redirect?

Comment: Does the words 'תוצאות החיפוש' are const? ;)

Comment: Yes, they are. It means "search results"

Comment: What are the rules of the redirect? Do the value of 'search_keyword'  can be changed? Please expand.

Comment: @utor I edited the question, hoping it's more helpful now.

Answer (score 1):

You must capture the search string and use it in the substitution URL

```
RewriteRule ^תוצאות_חיפוש:(.+)$ /?s=$1&post_type=product [L]
```

See [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) for details.

---

Although, I've never seen anything beyond ASCII in .htaccess file, 
I just checked this in my test environment. Even though, Apache logs this request as

> 172.17.0.1 - - [12/May/2019:14:58:39 +0000] "GET /%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9:shirts HTTP/1.1" 200 268 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.86 Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"

in mod_rewrite the `RewriteRule` receives it as decoded `תוצאות_חיפוש:shirts`

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
url_string_name.replace(@"^\/תוצאות_חיפוש:", "/?s=");
```

This will replace the begining of the url. And then:

```
url_string_name.replace(@"$", "&post_type=product");
```

this will replace the end of the url;
`^` means begin of string, `$` means end of string.
Good Luck!

Comment: You can do it too without regex, just by using 'replace' and 'add'.

Comment: Is it suppose to come after a certain code like `RewriteEngine ON` or wherever in the htaccess file?

Comment: I think you can write it wherever. Did you tried it?

Comment: I think it's because the Hebrew

Comment: @starkeen I see. How can I accomplish such a thing within the htaccess file or alternatively through php but before any headers are sent? (I'm using WordPress)